# PyQT: SQL Query runs, but doesn't display output in QTableView for a larger query

Tags: sql-server, pyqt4

I am creating an application in PyQt where in on clicking a button, the query runs and returns the output in QTableView. This is the code with which I am trying to achieve this:

```
self.table2 = QTableView()
projectModel1.setQuery("select * from xyz")
self.table2.setModel(projectModel1)
```

My problem is that this seems to work perfectly for a relatively small query, but when I replace the query with a larger query which creates a table in my database, it returns no output (let's call this large query as *'Query A'*). But when I check my database, I see that the table was created, which means *'Query A'* ran but didn't return the result. And also doesn't allow any other query after *'Query A'* to run.

I have tried running the query in SQL and the *'Query A'* works fine, so that is not the issue.

**What I want to know is that is there some restriction like that on the query size? And why is that even the queries after this query don't run?**

This is the *'Query A'* to understand the complexity of the query:

```
Declare @d as datetime, @w as INT, @y as INT, @x as INT, @z as Int, @yy as INT, @maxweek as Int, @ww as Int, @dd as datetime, @t as varchar(20) SET @d= getdate() set @t ='/12/31' SET @w = (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @d) / 7 * 7 + 3)+6) / 7 SET @w=@w-4 SET @y =year(getdate()) SET @x=@y*100+@w if @w <= 0 Begin set @yy = year(getdate())-1 set @dd = cast(cast(@yy as Varchar(10))+ @t + ' 11:11:11'  as datetime) set @maxweek = (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @dd) / 7 * 7 + 3)+6) / 7 set @ww= @maxweek + @w set @w= 1 set @y=@yy set @z=@yy*100+@ww set @x=@y*100+@w end else set @z=@x 
SELECT s.Name, s.CountryId, AVG(s.Timecalc) as MedianBusLOI FROM ( 
SELECT imp.name ,Week, i.countryId, 
datediff(ss, r.Begin, r.End) As Timecalc,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imp.name  ,Week, dataleverantor ORDER BY datediff(ss, r.Begin, r.End) ASC, Foreignid ASC) AS RowAsc,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imp.name  ,Week, dataleverantor ORDER BY datediff(ss, r.SurveyBegin, r.SurveyEnd) DESC, Foreignid DESC) AS RowDesc 
FROM People r inner join Imports imp on imp.id=r.importid 
inner join interview i on i.id = r.InternalRespondentId 
WHERE imp.name is not null and r.year*100 + r.week >= @x  and r.year*100 + r.week >= @z ) s 
WHERE s.RowAsc IN (s.RowDesc, s.RowDesc - 1, s.RowDesc + 1) GROUP BY s.name, countryId
```

All that this query does is that it calculates the median time taken by a person to complete filling a form. The query has no issues, it works perfectly.

Comment: From [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#exec): "For SQLite, the query string can contain only one statement at a time.  If more than one statement is given, the function returns false".

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro, I am using MS SQL

Comment: @ekhumoro: And I have put the entire query in a single line, but for ease of understanding put it in various lines above

Comment: Does `setQuery` return `True` for both statements? Have you checked `projectModel.lastError()` to see if an error occured? Did you call `projectModel.select()` after setting the query, and does it return `True`?

Comment: @ekhumoro: I checked `projectModel.lastError()` and it returned a blank space.  When I call 'projectModel.select()' it gives me an error that -AttributeError: 'QSqlQueryModel' object has no attribute 'select'
and printing 'projectModel.setquery("xyz")' returns None

Comment: @ekhumoro: My problem did get solved though just by creating a new connection and running the first query in the new connection and the second query in the old connection. Would you know why does that solve the issue? Both the connections are absolutely identical and I haven't made any changes to the queries

Comment: I don't know. And you have not provided a [mcve], which makes it very difficult to analyse properly. (Even if you had, I wouldn't be able to do that myself, since I cannot do any testing with MS SQL).

Comment: @ekhumoro: Okay I understand and i'll henceforth try to provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example. Thanks for all your help!